# Compound DisplayMemberPath for a combobox

Tags: c#, combobox

I need to create a DisplayMemberPath that is a compound of a few properties (ie object.category.Name+" -> "+object.description) I'm pretty sure I can do this by creating a dynamic data type that encapsulates the object and also adds a new property called displayField that is what I need but I'm wondering if there is a more proper way to do this that does not involve creating a new object. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`DisplayMemberPath` is just a "shortcut" for when you don't need a complex template for items. If you need more control, use `ItemTemplate` instead:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} -> {1}">
                        <Binding Path="Category.Name" />
                        <Binding Path="Description" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Thanks! How does that bind specifically to displaymemberpath. For example, what if I wanted two item templates, one for selectedvaluepath and one for dislaymemberpath?

Comment: @user978744, you can specify the ItemTemplate instead of the DisplayMemberPath, but you can't do the same for SelectedValuePath, it wouldn't make sense, since the selected value isn't something that is displayed. If you need a compound SelectedValue, create a new property on your ViewModel

Comment: What are the first set of curly braces in the `{}{0} -> {1}` StringFormat attribute for?